# onClick event on react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn MEAN and I was trying to make an Easy Pokemon finder.

The thing is that i'm having troubles with events attaching to a component.

Here is the main view:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

/* Import Components */
import Search from './components/Search/Search';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

/* Import Actions */
import { fetchByName } from './PokedexActions';

// Import Style
//import styles from './Pokedex.css';

class Pokedex extends Component {

  handleFind= (name) =>{
    this.props.dispatch(fetchByName({name}));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col md={4}>
            <Search findPokemon={this.handleFind}/>
          </Col>
          <Col md={4}></Col>
          <Col md={4}></Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {};
};

Pokedex.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Pokedex);
```

and here it's the search componenet:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { ControlLabel, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Search extends Component {

  handleClick(){
    console.log("algo");
    this.props.findPokemon('eevee');
    //console.log(this.refs.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ControlLabel>Pokemon Search</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Pokemon" ref="name" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
        <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Find</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Search.propTypes = {
  findPokemon: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Search;
```

Unfortunately it won't get fired the events attached to neither button nor form Control...

Anybody knows what it could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do yo mean handleClick () method not getting fired?

Comment: Try `onClick={() => this.handleClick()}`

Comment: onChange={this.handleClick} should be onChange={this.handleClick.bind(this)}

Comment: @Ved yes the handleClick() method

Comment: @RicardoACB are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @Ved no error at all...

Comment: @RicardoACB do you see  output of console.log("algo"); in console.?

Comment: @Ved no i'm not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like [Ved](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3265777/ved) mentioned, you should use `onChange={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` instead of `onChange={this.handleClick}`.

However, you could add constructor for class `Pokedex` to get more readability.

```
export class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  // the rest of code...
}
```

Comment: Is it still necessary to bind these handlers in 2022 with the latest react?